# Nimble vs Agile

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Because of their similar definitions, could you tell me how they are used in different contexts?

The definition of the word **[nimble](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/nimble)** from MacMillan Dictionary:

> 1. able to move quickly and easily
>      **Synonyms and related words**
>      Words used to describe fast movement: fast, quick, swift...
> 2. someone who has a nimble mind is intelligent and learns things quickly
>      **Synonyms and related words**
>      Words used to describe intelligent or wise people: genius, intelligent,
>      wise...

---

The definition of the word **[agile](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/agile)** from MacMillan Dictionary:

> 1. able to move quickly and easily
>      The ferret is an agile hunter.
>      **Synonyms and related words**
>      Words used to describe fast movement: fast, quick, swift...
> 2. able to think quickly, solve problems, and have new ideas
>      an agile mind
>      **Synonyms and related words**
>      Words used to describe intelligent or wise people: genius, intelligent,
>      wise...

Comment: This is matter for several questions, not one; and they're all of a sort most conveniently answered with a good dictionary. If that leaves you in any doubt, you may click on the *edit* link above to revise your question, citing what you find in the dictionary and addressing more specific issues.

Comment: @StoneyB Could you chek the question out again please

Comment: These are really close in meaning. A horse, a person, an athlete, etc. can be agile and nimble. This is saying the same thing two times. There is no extra meaning added by using both words. So, take your pick of either word. The only difference in usage off the top of my head is that *agile* might be used for larger people (including horses) while *nimble* might be used for smaller people. In *[Jack be nimble, Jack be quick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Be_Nimble),* the word *agile* could be used with pretty much zero change in meaning. It is just that *nimble* sounds better here.

Answer (score 1):

Nimble: the ability to be very deliberate and precise.

Agile: being flexible or able to use your fingers in many ways.

> 1. Threading a needle requires very precise and **nimble** movements.
> 2. To be able to climb to the top of the tower before time is called, you must be very **agile**.

Sentence 1 means you have to be delicate and precise when threading a needle because of how small the eye of the needle is.

Sentence 2 means you have to move quickly and easily so that you can climb to the top before you run out of time.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, not even native, just sharing what I understand from all the dictionary definitions and examples I read. The difference seems to be:

- Nimble is about grasping
- Agile is about reacting

So if you're talking about using one's brain, one would be

- nimble at understanding concepts, learning things in detail, interpreting the situation, etc.
- agile at reacting to changes in the situation, changing your focus to start learning an emerging idea, abandoning an obsolete idea, changing strategy when current one is failing (which requires being nimble at recognizing the failure), etc.

Same difference with respect to using extremities in an agile vs nimble way.